# How to access packagemanager in viewmodel

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I was using fragment and now I attached ViewModel to it and was transferring code to ViewModel and `activity?.packageManager?.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)` this line shows an error. How can I access package manager in ViewModel?

Answer (score 1):

On way is to extend `AndroidViewModel` instead of `ViewModel` as:

```
class MyFragmentViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
...
```

Now you can call:

```
application.packageManager?.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
```

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically if you are implementing MVVM pattern (I see you implementing ViewModel), android.* layer should be handled in the View, Activities/Contexts shouldn't be managed in the ViewModel to avoid Memory Leaks. Even though, depending on the project context, of course this rule **doesn't apply to every single project context**, I think the best approach would be (if not Dependency Injection is been used) to have an Application Provider.

Create an object:

```
object ApplicationProvider {

    @Volatile
    lateinit var application: Application

    fun initialize(_application: Application) {
        if (!::application.isInitialized) {
            synchronized(this) {
                application = _application
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your MainActivity, initialise the ApplicationProvider as the following:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        
        ApplicationProvider.initialize(this.application)
    }
```

Now you can access the ApplicationContext in your whole project where is needed with:

```
ApplicationProvider.application.applicationContext
```

**Remember to not assign ApplicationContext to static fields (as a val e.g.) to avoid Memory Leaks.**

PD: I'm not very fan of AndroidViewModel, but I guess it is a good solution as well, as a colleague mentioned before :D